# Execute compiled ClojureScript from the commandline with Rhino

Tags: command-line, rhino, clojurescript

I understand ClojureScript can be executed within a JavaScript REPL or it can be compiled into JavaScript, then run in a browser.  I couldn't find a way to use it on the server side with Rhino.  Here is my way of thinking, I have a simple source file:

```
(ns simple.hello)

(println "Hello, world")
```

I compile it to `hello.js`.  I try to run

```
java -jar js.jar out/goog/base.js out/goog/deps.js out/hello.js
```

Nothing happens.  How can I make it work, or is only Node.js supported on the command line?

Comment: What compiler settings are you using? What does the contents of hello.js look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

src/app.js:

```
(ns simple.app)

(ns hello)
(defn ^:export greet [n]
  (print (str "Hello " n)))

(greet "World")
```

To compile:

```
cljsc src '{:optimizations :advanced}' > app-prod.js
```

Then, to run with Rhino:

```
java -jar js.jar app-prod.js
```

Output: Hello World

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think the problem is caused when generating a javascript file without optimizations.