# Generate a Java class from Clojurescript using Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, clojure, rhino, clojurescript

I'd like to do the following: I have a simple function written in Clojure/ClojureScript:

```
(defn add
  [a b]
  (+ a b))
```

I want to wrap this function into a Java class and put it in a jar so that I can access it in an existing Java/Android project. My previous approach was to use **gen-class** and create an uberjar. This however leads to some [problems](http://nicholaskariniemi.github.io/2014/03/12/clojure-android-startup-benchmarks.html).

As an alternative approach I considered compiling the function using ClojureScript (a solution also suggested by [Sam Beran](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/foeLiIDx4q8)).

So far I understand how to:

- [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231550/has-anyone-used-or-written-an-ant-task-to-compile-rhino-javascript-to-java-byt/3567406#3567406) javascript files into [Java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055855/how-to-invoke-rhino-compiled-javascript-methods-class-files-in-the-java-progra/5057303#5057303)
- put them in a .jar
- Compile ClojureScript

I'm not struggling to get the ClojureScript output into a format that can be passed on to the Rhino compiler.

Any thoughts?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: I **do not** want to create a class with a main function as is [done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738135/execute-compiled-clojurescript-from-the-commandline-with-rhino)!

Answer (score 1):

One general way of going about this would be to:

At build time:

- run the ClojureScript compiler to generate a JavaScript file
- put the JavaScript file into the resource directory.
- compile the Java class that uses it
- make a jar file (an Uberjar or a normal Unterjar)

this Java class should:

- make a java class that on initialization start up Rhino
- on instantiation runs the javascript from the resource.

On a desktop of server you may not get the same awesome startup times My. Beran reported on android because processes on android have the advantage of starting life with a warmed up runtime with Rhino ready to go from the moment they start (they inherit it from the Zygote process)

Comment: Yes. But this approach yields a problem. From Sam Berans post: "[...], Startup speed was around 8-10 seconds - even worse than JVM Clojure! Some quick measurements indicated that the bulk of the time was spent with Rhino parsing the JS sources for cljs/core.js. I was pleased to discover that Rhino supports bytecode precompilation via the jsc utility [3]. I was able to precompile the ClojureScript output to bytecode, and achieve much faster startup - around 150ms on device. This is well within the target performance range, and is fast enough to eliminate any noticeable UI lag."